# How to position dynamically appended div close to the other dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am making a comment system with reply option. So basically I have two type of comment one parent comment and other is child comment (subcomment).

For this system, I am submitting both these input using ajax and then I append the response of the PHP script to create a dummy that I use to display to the user the recently submitted comment by him and I use the same thing in submitting the sub-comment.

**BUT** *how to tell the position of appended sub-comment dummy which is below to the parent comment*.

ajax code using for submitting parent comment:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "submit_cmt.php",
       data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(response)
       {
          // alert(response); // show response from the php script.
          $('#comment').append(response); 
          onsuccess();            
       }
     });
});
```

Then I do query and select the comment_id from database which then I use to submit the reply of the comment, and for submitting the reply (sub-comment) I use this ajax code:

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "submit_subcmt.php",
  data: form2.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
  success: function(response)
  {
   $('.subcomment').append(response); 
  onsubcmt_success();  
  }
```

**Output I want**

- comment(a)

subcmt(a)

subcmt(a)

- comment(b)

subcmt(b)

subcmt(b)

But **Output I am getting**

- comment(a)

subcmt(a)

subcmt(a)

- comment(b)

subcmt(a)    // subcomment dummy displaying below every comment

subcmt(b)

Comment: Based on the title, this sounds more like a CSS problem than any of the tags listed.  Can you be more specific about what you intend to accomplish?  Can you add a screenshot to show us what is happening?

Comment: Can you share the HTML code so that we can understand how it looks and where are the #comment and .subcomment elements placed?

Comment: updated question showing the output i want with output i am getting

Comment: Can you please share your html code which shows this comment & sub comment?

Comment: So, does `.prepend()` instead of `.append()` do what you want ? Could you clarify what do you want exactly? Your example is a bit confusing with the (a) and (b)'s